# SoundEffect.GetSampleSizeInBytes how it works?

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-7, xna

I found in xna this method to calculate the length of an audio sample based on the duration, sample rate and number of channel.

for example if I call the method:

```
int number = SoundEffect.GetSampleSizeInBytes(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), 44100, AudioChannels.Mono);

number = 88200;
```

I want use a similar function in android, but I have not found anything like.

So, what is the formula to calculate the length of an audio sample, starting from those parameters?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sample is 2 bytes. So, `Mono` have 2 bytes per sample, `Stereo` - 4 bytes.

If you have 44100 samples per seconds with `Mono` and your audio duration is 1 seconds, total bytes length will be:
44100 sample/second * 2 bytes/sample * 1 channel * 1 second = 88200 bytes